# Android Proguard doesn't shrink APK

Tags: android, android-proguard

Title sums it up - my app is the same size installed on the device with and without Proguard and the APK is the same size on disk.  I unzipped the APK and the dex files account for about 72% of it, so minifying should have a significant effect (unless I'm using every class and method from every dependency I've included, which is not plausible).  I'm using the standard rules file plus one of my own with a few keep rules.

Gradle file:

```
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
```

`proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

I thought there would be a ton of information about this problem but as far as I can tell there's almost nothing.

Comment: I am not sure how much other dependencies you have but if you are doing -keep all retrofit classes, it doesn't look like you are trying to minimize. 
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2230#issuecomment-236068544

Perhaps you are minimizing for other dependencies which I don't see here, though.

Comment: There are lots of other dependencies.  I just copied those rules from the retrofit documentation.

Comment: agree with @Emma, What other dependencies do you have? You need other rules for the other dependencies.

Comment: Why do I need rules for other dependencies?  Won't ProGuard remove unused code by default unless a rule specifies otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

`minifyEnabled true`: it runs ProGuard

`shrinkResources true`: it removes resources that ProGuard flagged as unused.

While removing unwanted files from your DEX, your APK size also reduces.

Comment: `shrinkResources` is for resources, obviously, but ProGuard is supposed to "minify" the APK by removing unused code.  It isn't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `proguard-android-optimize.txt` and not `proguard-android.txt` as the base proguard config file.

The first one configures both obfuscation and optimization while the latter configures only obfuscation.

Comment: It's about the same size with `proguard-android-optimize.txt`.

Comment: Additionally if you have `-dontoptimize` in any of the configs, that prevents the optimizer from running.